# URL with javascript actions included

Tags: javascript, url

I have one page with many DIVS, they are all hidden. Only when certain link is clicked, corresponding DIV is displayed...

The question is:
Is there any way to compose a URL which would contain instruction that is otherwise performed when a link is clicked on a loaded page?

To clarify:

It is a page with many DIVS (display: none)

only links are displayed.

When a link is clicked, corresponding DIV is display: block.

the URL of that page is: www.mywebsite.com/OurServices

Is there a way, I can generate or create somehow a URL that would go like
www.mywebsite.com/OurServices+JS-clicked-link-to-display-certain-service....

Thank you!

Comment: So that I can send some users a URL link with specific Service DIV displayed... thanks!

Comment: you can attach a `#` hash to the URL so that it becomes  `www.mywebsite.com/OurServices#div1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use URL Variables like this

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1&image=awesome.jpg
```

Heres a js function to read them

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}
```

then call it like this

```
getQueryVariable("id");
```

which would return "1" or

```
getQueryVariable("image");
```

which would return "awesome.jpg"

then check against it

```
if(getQueryVariable("id") == "1"){
      ///Add remove css class to hide show
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash values for this:
www.mywebsite.com/OurServices#div1

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var hashValue = location.hash;  
  hashValue = hashValue.replace(/^#/, '');  
  //do something with the value here  
  $('#'+hashValue).show();
});
```

Comment: Why remove the hash and then add it back?

Answer (score 1):

you can attach a hash value to url when user clicks the link

window.location.hash=value

on load just you need to check the url values

eg.

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var value = (window.location.hash).split('#')[1];
    // hide or show divs based on value
}, false );
```

based on value just show and hide the divs.